# C++, Visual Studio: unexpected std::async return type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, future, stdasync

I'm trying to save multiple `std::future`s in a `QMap`. The `QMap` is a member variable of my class:

```cpp
QMap<QString, std::future<cv::Mat>> threads;
```

I now want to store the results of multiple `std::async` calls in this map, like this:

```cpp
this->threads.insert(filename, std::async(std::launch::async, &MainInterface::readImage, this, path, true));
```

The function `readImage`, that is called asynchronously here, looks like this:

```cpp
cv::Mat MainInterface::readImage(QString path, bool emitSignals) {
    //some code
    return image;
}
```

So the return value of the async function should be an `std::future<cv::Mat>` I think. However, when trying to compile, Visual Studio 2015 gives me the following compier error:

```cpp
no instance of overloaded function "QMap<Key, T>::insert [with Key=QString, T=std::future<cv::Mat>]" matches the argument list, argument types are: (QString, std::future<cv::Mat (&)(QString path, bool emitSignals)>), object type is: QMap<QString, std::future<cv::Mat>>
```

What puzzles me is the return type `std::future<cv::Mat (&)(QString path, bool emitSignals)>`, which is different from the `std::future<cv::Mat>` that I expected.

Comment: `std::future` is not copyable, is `QMap::insert` for move-only types? have you checked with `std::shared_future` ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried it with `std::shared_future`, yet. If I use the `operator[]` to insert into the `QMap`, IntelliSense still shows me an error message, but the program compiles and launches.

Comment: That looks like an IntelliSense error. What is the MSVC compiler error? It could be useful to look at the Output tab, not the Error List tab.

Comment: What I postet was the actual compiler error, not the IntelliSense message. If I modify the code as mentioned in the comment above, there is no compiler error (however, still an IntelliSense message).

Comment: MSVC errors have an error code of the form `Cxxxx`; what error code does this one have?